# UILabel didSet attributedText not called after set in text:didSet

Tags: swift, uikit, uilabel, property-observer

In a subclass of UILabel I add format on the text and set the attributedText in the following way

```
    open override var text: String? {
        didSet {
            …
            attributedText =
        }
    }
```

I also had some code in `attributedText - didSet:` but this is not called after setting text. I can't figure out why. Is there something missing?

Comment: didSet never called? Could it be because the 'open' flag?

Comment: When is the text property being set? I have tested this myself and works just fine.